# Adding views to the layout programatically (and inflating) is very slow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView which contains multiple Views (around 30) where each of them is page/height long.

Each page inside RecyclerView contains views that can be also scrolled horizontally (around 20 views in 1st horizontal scroll view) and (around 10 views in 2nd horizontal scroll view).

Which means that each RecyclerView creates around 30 views (and inflates them) every time view is created. This is very, very slow.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            View details = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.details, parent, false);
            viewHolder.container.addView(details);
        }
```

I have tried multiple things such as nested RecyclerViews but it's equally slow. Is there a good solution to create multiple views for each page without getting hit by performance (mostly seen when scrolling vertically and only for a second but still very annoying).

So far my best solution is RecyclerView + nested RecyclerView for each page and Horizontall Scroll View which creates less layouts (just 10 instead of 20 and they are simple).

Thanks

Comment: where do you create that views?

Comment: in onCreateView in RecyclerView Adapter, I will mark the question as solved as I found what is causing such a bad performance. It's nested weights and it looks like peter answer is the best when layout is properly done.

Comment: you mean onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create views now using bit different approach and see if that can solve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try only getting the LayoutInflater once outside the loop and letting it add to your container view.
(this assumes `parent` and `viewHolder.container` are the same)

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        View details = inflator.inflate(R.layout.details, viewHolder.container, true);
    }
```

Comment: Tried it just now, there is still performance hit - it got faster but not much.

Comment: The perhaps the details xml needs some optimisation.  Can you add this xml layout to your question too? If you are unable to,  run the [android lint tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) and go thru its sugestions for this file.

Comment: I can't share layout file as it is internal-company application. Sorry. I can add that by adding the layout manually @include layout many times in the .xml file is not getting performance hit.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html <-- full link.  This will help you.  It also come in Android Studio and IntelliJ using the warnings interface in code editors.

Comment: Then use the include tag for now.

Comment: I will use lint now and see what I can find, I thought about using include but each view might contain 2 or 10 or 5 views (depends on the data). This is quite ugly approach.

Comment: Just a follow up regarding the answer @petey answer is actually correct and most efficient. The problem from the beginning was RecyclerView itself which made the views really slow. I got it fixed by calling the method setHasStableIds(true).